# How to specify multiple tags when viewing questions by tag?

Tags: support, tags, questions, filtering

Here is the url I am talking about

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1

I would like to view questions tagged say either as `tag1` or `tag2`.

How should I go about it?

If I type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1+tag2

It shows questions which have `tag1` and `tag2`.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1%20or%20tag2

Comment: @vaultah 

Thank you!!